# Unable to install packages in latest version of RStudio and R Version.3.1.1

Tags: r

I am unable to install packages through  latest version of `RStudio and R Version.3.1.1.` Kindly help. I got the error as mentioned below:

```
Example:
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘reshape’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Comment: Firewall/proxy issue? Did it work before?

Comment: Response on RStudio support site: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200522573-Can-t-install-packages

Comment: I had this problem too. The solution was to use another mirror.

Comment: Following these steps solved my issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4421#issuecomment-327033866

In Terminal, run `conda install libssh2` then `conda install krb5`

Comment: I tried everything, however only reinstalling R and Rstudio worked for me. I later installed it in Anaconda.

Answer (score 157):

Not 100% certain that you have the same problem, but I found out the hard way that my job blocks each mirror site option that was offered and I was getting errors like this:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  unsupported URL scheme
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Workaround (I am using CentOS)...

```
install.packages('package_name', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

I hope this saves someone hours of frustration.

Comment: Strange for me as I was able to install packages no problem until this morning... But this worked immediately.

Comment: also, check that the ```download.file.method``` isn't set in your RProfile.  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897-Secure-Package-Downloads-for-R

Comment: Also note that you may get `unable to access index for repository` if trying to use `https` instead of `http`

Comment: how does install.packages() method work when we specify repos as `repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')` instead of `http://cran.us.r-project.org`

Comment: I am really not sure, but you can certainly try it out to see if it does -- let me know if it works @Regressor.

Answer (score 76):

I think this is the "set it and forget it" solution:

```
options(repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

Note that this isn't https. I was on a Linux machine, ssh'ing in. If I used https, it didn't work.

Comment: My problem went away from repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/' to ...http...

Comment: Tools -> Global Options -> Packages --> I unchecked use secure download method for HTTP, it worked, all issues disappeared, R also provides that option, you need to select "other mirrors" and select 0 Clould and hit OK

Comment: Worked like a charm.... I was trying to use HTTPS and it was giving me an error is not valid for rstudio3.1 and it solved the problem thanks....

Comment: Didn't work for me on Linux Mint 19 with RStudio 1.2 and R 3.4.4, what am I doing wrong? It always returns: `Installing package into ‘/home/leon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :  package ‘pacman’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)`

Answer (score 7):

As @Pascal said, it is likely that you encounter problem with the firewall or/and proxy issue. 
As a first step, go through **[FAQ on the CRAN web page](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e)**. After that, try to flag R with *--internet2*.

Sometimes it could be useful to check global options in R studio and uncheck "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP".
Tools -> Global Options -> Packages and unchecking the "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP" option.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Based on answers from the community, there appear to be several ways that might solve this:

1. From the [official FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e) and [support forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20190802093505/https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200522573-Can-t-install-packages?mobile_site=true) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601094/4143855), you may have have a firewall or proxy issue that is blocking RStudio from connecting to the internet:

- Disable any firewalls
- *Tools -> Global Options -> Packages* and unchecking the *"Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP"* option and restart R ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747127/4143855), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403418/4143855), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477344/4143855))
- Flag R with *--internet2*
- On CentOS [it was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33283585/4143855) to try the following: `install.packages('package_name', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

2. Several answers suggest using an alternate mirror ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31236454/4143855), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31344396/4143855), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403418/4143855)):

- *Preferences > General > Default working directory > Browse* and switch your mirror from local/global (whichever is unchecked)

3. On Windows you can start the application with `http_proxy=http://host:port/`:

- `"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" http_proxy=http://host:port/`

5. Shut down and restart. Needed after many of the above operations, and [suggested standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33685170/4143855).

Comment: One more: this error occurs if there is no more space on the harddrive (Windows)

Comment: I don't see the option "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP", only "Enable packages pane" and "Use secure download method for HTTP". What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

My solution that worked was to open R studio options and select global miror (the field was empty before) and the error went away.

Comment: where exactly did you find that option?

Comment: indeed please add this essential information.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following to be able to install new packages:

1- In Tools -> Global Options -> Packages, uncheck the "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP" option,

2- In Tools -> Global Options -> Packages, change the CRAN mirror to "0- Cloud - Rstudio, automatic redirection to servers worldwide"

3- Restart Rstudio.

4- Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, try this:

`"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" http_proxy=http://host:port/`

Comment: Where do I type this? Inside RStudio or CMD?

Comment: @Pragyaditya Das Type into a command prompt.  Open one with: WindowsKey+R > type "cmd" > Enter.  Don't forget to replace "host" and "port" with the actual numbers ;-)

Comment: How do I find the host and port numbers?

Comment: @Pragyaditya Das These are the host name or host IP address and port number for your own site's proxy server. You should ask someone locally.  Or check the settings in your browser to see what proxy is set and try those settings.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time @cer solution works but if in case its not working then try installing it in base R (NOT in R studio). As R studio runs base R executable in background so new package will be available in R studio as well. [my experience in macOS]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Preferences-General-Default working directory-Browse Switch from global to local mirror

Working on a Mac. 10.10.3