# Gain Package Installation error in R 3.1.2

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install the Gains package in R Studio Version 3.1.2 like this:
install.packages("gains")

The following warnings appear:
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning in install.packages :package ‘gains’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem lies in your corrupted, incomplete or otherwise incorrect `R` environment. I was able to install that package without any problems at all just by issuing the default command:

```
> install.packages("gains")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/gains_1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 35802 bytes (34 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 34 Kb

package ‘gains’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSSRths\downloaded_packages
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

As a quick solution to the problem, I suggest to specify CRAN mirror explicitly:

```
install.packages("gains", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried suggesting the CRAN mirror explicitly and I still get the warning that:package ‘gains’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2).I've noticed you have the R 3.1.1 version

Comment: @RodicaC: I just updated `R` to 3.1.2 on MS Windows and my advice still works fine. Try `install.packages("gains", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com", type = "source")`.

Comment: I've tried the previous advice and I still get the same error... I suppose is something with my R environment, but I don't know what exactly.Thanks!

Comment: @RodicaC: Well, in that case re-installing `R` (and, if needed, `RStudio`) might be the easiest way to return your `R` environment back to normal. Give it a try and let us know. You're welcome!

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Seems a little overkill.  I think they should try the stuff in the link I have in the comments on the question before nuking R (which I don't think would help in this case).

Comment: @Dason: Reviewing the error message again, I think that you're most likely right. I hope that your referenced solution will help.