# InternetOpenUrl failed: '' download.file in R

Tags: r, ftp

I am trying to download a file with the following : "download.file(url,"DB.zip", "auto", quiet = FALSE, mode = "wb",
              cacheOK = TRUE)"

But I keep getting an error stating
            In download.file(url, "DB.zip", "auto", quiet = FALSE, mode = "wb",  :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
             I've searched countless places and haven't found a valid reason. and everyone says theirs is working

Comment: Have you simply tried: download.file(url, "DB.zip")?

Comment: What's the url so we can try?

Comment: I have tried that as well and it gives me the same error. @Dominic I would like to but the credentials and data are too sensitive to give away.

Comment: Yikes, that makes it really hard to help... maybe give the most details you can give about it - url is ftp or http? Did you try several other combinations of arguments?

Comment: Yeah I have. I tried it with "wget" and "curl" but those give me a 127 error :"download had nonzero exit status" I am using an ftp url and it is just the ip address with credentials.

Comment: duplicate:path/to/dupe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install packages in latest version of RStudio and R Version.3.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1)