# download.file() error: InternetOpenURL failed: 'An error occurred in the secure channel support'

Tags: r, http, curl, github, devtools

I am trying to install a package (gg3D) from GitHub in Rstudio.  I was unable to install it using

```
devtools::install_github("AckerDWM/gg3D")
```

(Error: Failed to install 'gg3D' from GitHub).  I tried changing the download method (`curl`, `libcurl`, etc.) but to no avail. Then I decided to download the source file and try to install it manually.  Downloading the file did not work either:

```
source_URL <- "http://github.com/repos/AckerDWM/gg3D/archive/master.zip"
utils::download.file(source_URL, destfile = "tmp.zip")
```

This is when I get the error: `InternetOpenURL failed: 'An error occurred in the secure channel support'`

I believe this is a firewall/proxy issue (I have no problem downloading this on another computer with similar specs).

In case it's helpful, I'm running R version 3.6.1 on Windows 7.

---

Focusing solely on the downloading error, **what I have tried**:

1. Changing the download.file `method` (which is `wininet` by default), e.g.

   - `utils::download.file(source_URL, destfile = "tmp.zip", method = "libcurl")` returns as `HTTP status was '404 Not Found'` error;
   - `utils::download.file(source_URL, destfile = "tmp.zip", method = "curl")` returns `'curl' call had nonzero exit status`;
   - As above for `method = "wget"`.
2. On the RStudio menu, Tools > Global Options... > Packages > and unchecking the box “Use secure download method for HTTP”. Has no effect.
3. `setInternet2(use = FALSE)` (R warns that this is defunct).
4. Trying both `http` and `https`.

These proposed solutions came from the following linked SO articles (but they did not work for me):

- [R - when trying to install package: InternetOpenUrl failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355444/r-when-trying-to-install-package-internetopenurl-failed)
- [Unable to install packages in latest version of RStudio and R Version.3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1)
- [Download.file fails in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721819/download-file-fails-in-rstudio)

Similar to (no solutions):

- [installr::updateR() In addition: Warning message: In file(con, "r") : InternetOpenUrl failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505611/installrupdater-in-addition-warning-message-in-filecon-r-internetop)

  - [InternetOpenUrl failed: '' download.file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086838/internetopenurl-failed-download-file-in-r?lq=1)

Comment: In the past, I had a similar issue which was resolved by changing the CRAN mirror.  Unfortuntely, being a package on Github, this isn't an option.  But it does make me think it is a firewall/proxy issue (based on language used on linked SO articles - I don't actually know what this means).

Comment: I've just tested this on my home computer (no firewall) and I get the same error.  So that is: 1 success (no error) for a work computer on ethernet; 1 error on laptop on same work network connecting via wifi; and 1 error on home computer/network.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue but with other package. Tried changing the CRAN mirror but not worked. Then found some help on Microsoft page and changed some settings in Internet Option from Control Panel. Make sure you have checked SSL 2.0 & 3.0. Also, check the TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. This change resolved my problem. Hope this helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the computer that this problem occured on to test if this solves the problem for me. But hopefully it helps someone else with this problem.