# unable to install caret package in R

Tags: r, package, installation

When I try to install caret package in R I get the following error message:

```
 utils:::menuInstallPkgs()

--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(NULL, .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  no packages were specified
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed:
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you encounter any problems while installing other packages?

Comment: got same error message when trying to install other packages:

Comment: what is the OS you are on?

Comment: please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355444/r-when-trying-to-install-package-internetopenurl-failed

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following methods:

Edit: changed https to http

```
install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/caret_6.0-80.tar.gz",
                 repos=NULL, method="libcurl")
```

or

```
library(devtools)
install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/caret_6.0-80.tar.gz")
```