# Problem finding packages while trying to install them in R

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm trying to install some packages, including "ggplot2", "GEOquery", "limma", etc.
Meanwhile, I keep facing either one of the errors mentioned below:
(And the same errors with a different repository for "ggplot2" and "limma")

```
install.packages("GEOquery")
```

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/bioc/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘GEOquery’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)

Comment: Can you follow the link to PACKAGES in your web browser? Can you evaluate the command `read.dcf(url("https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES"))` in R?

Comment: I could open the link in my browser. But I have the error mentioned below while trying to run your suggested command:
`Error in read.dcf(url("https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(url("https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES")) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'P¼'
`
@MartinMorgan

Answer (score 0):

Follow the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33372798/547331) and try `options(download.file.method="libcurl"))`.