# Unable to install R packages for R 4.1

Tags: r, install.packages

I am unable to install any R packages today. The issue did not happen until last week (the last time I use the command). My laptop system is a Windows 10, and I am not using any local network/proxy/work Internet, so pretty sure it is not the proxy server or firewall issue. I updated my R, restart the program and the computer, no help.

Here is the error message.

> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
> 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Here are the methods I have tried from the Internet but did NOT work:

1. Update the CRAN Repository for installing packages
2. Uncheck the "Use secure download method for HTTP" and "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP" options
3. Run R as administrator
4. Change the library to install packages
5. Use the `install.packages('package_name', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

Again, I am pretty sure there is no firewall/proxy issue, as I never had the problem until last week, using the same Internet and the same device. Does anyone have ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I had no problem opening: 
http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES
This is http not https... maybe you need use https instead of http

Comment: Make sure you can access the URL from your web browser. http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES. If you cannot, then it's not an R issue, it's a network configuration issue. It's unclear who controls your internet network settings but make sure you can access the website.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. I can open the URL with my browser.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga I had no problem using a browser, either. With my R, neither http nor https works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was eventually solved by `options(download.file.method="libcurl")`.

Following another suggested answer, I tried `options(repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")` but got the below message:

> Warning message:
> In download.file(mirrors_csv_url, destfile = mirrors_csv, quiet = TRUE) :
> InternetOpenUrl failed: 'ìÂs°þ$'

Then [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355444/r-when-trying-to-install-package-internetopenurl-failed) did the trick.