# R studio no longer allowing me to download / install packages

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

Cant install packages

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

this is what i have tried so far

1. i have tried using a CRAN repository closer to me (im in sydney australia) - this didnt help
2. i have tried downloading rtools42 - didnt help
3. i have unchecked the box in packages "use secure download method for http"
4. i have even tried using an external repository

   > options(repos=c(cran="http://cran.rstudio.com"))
   > and then tried to install.packages
   > but that still didnt help

I really am not sure what to do

Comment: So you get the same unable to access error every time you try?  It sounds like the problem may be that you don't have internet access. Can you access other internet things besides r packages from R? For example, can you download a file using a URL?

Comment: Yep! Can access internet :)

Comment: Tried restarting the programs too
Didnt help :(

Comment: Are you comfortable using the command line?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355444/r-when-trying-to-install-package-internetopenurl-failed/33372798#33372798