# Error in installing packages in R studio

Tags: r

When i try to install packages in R studio, i am getting the below mentioned error. Can you guys help me in sorting out this issue?

```
install.packages("fPortfolio")
```

> Warning in install.packages :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
>   'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Comment: 1) Is your local internet working? 2) Have you tried selecting another CRAN mirror for downloading packages?

Comment: This may also be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1