# Unable to install R packages anymore- nothing helped so far

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I am sorry for asking the same question that has been asked many times before again but all the suggested solutions that worked for other users failed in my case... I was suddenly not able to install R packages anymore on my R version 3.3. and received the following error messsage:

```
    Warning in install.packages :
    unable to access index for repository http://cran.univ-paris1.fr    src/contrib:
    cannot open URL 'http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
    Warning in install.packages
```

I already tried several different mirrors which did not work. I even updated my R to the newest version (3.5.1) which also did not help. I changed the general options and unselected "secure download method for HTTP" and also "use internet explorer library/proxy for http")- without any success. Lastely, I was running "options(repos="my_favorite_CRAN_mirror")" before trying to install a package but it also failed.

Does anyone have an idea whatelse I could try? I start getting a bit desperate since nothing worked so far...any help would be highly appreciated!!! Thanks a lot!

Best wishes,
Belinda

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or/and proxy?

Comment: I have never seen such error but switching to Anaconda and using RStudio on it may help

Comment: @boyaronur Why would that help? As far as I can tell from questions on SO, Anaconda is more likely to make the problem worse.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. I thought when I would unselect the "use internet explorer library/proxy for http" option than it should not matter no? How can I check if I am behind a firewall, which is interferring with my R? Thanks for helping again!

Comment: can you download a package manually and then install from zip or tar.gz file? that might be a temporary solution until you figure it out

Comment: maybe there's an answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: Thanks for your response labtsnok. No installing a package manually from zip did also not work. Yes, I read the first link, you sent, but all the suggestions there did also fail unfortunately. I will have a look at the second link. Thanks!