# RStudio crashing when installing package with install.packages

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install packages in RStudio but just cannot do it. It has been  failing to install packages withour errors or warnings.

I had a problem earlier on to install texlive-full earlier on, and might have done something awkward to my /etc/apt/sources.list.d files. I had the following problem:

```
install.packages('rstanarm')
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r- 
project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES
```

Which was solved in another stackoverflow thread: [Unable to install packages in latest version of RStudio and R Version.3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1)

Upon running:
    install.packages('rstanarm', dependencies = T, , repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')

R fails with error:

```
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘[...]/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- 
library/3.6’ for modifying
Try removing ‘[...]/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK- 
rstanarm’
```

Once again, in stackoverflow I tried [R install.packages returns "failed to create lock directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory)

And running

```
install.packages('rstanarm', dependencies = T, , 
repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

Leads to RStudio crashing and closing in the middle of the installation.

This also happens for other packages. I have spent a few hours on this and on the brink of giving up. Anyone has an idea of what might be going on?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Were you able to install rstanarm in the end?

I'm running into similar problems, and I've tried almost everything, to no avail.

Comment: If I recall correctly, in the end I just waited and eventually it worked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name servers for r-project.org are either down or have no records for the domain name for the moment (at 0426UTC, 27JUN2019):

```html
<pre>

$ dig @ns2.wu-wien.ac.at r-project.org

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> @ns2.wu-wien.ac.at r-project.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


$ dig @ns6.gandi.net r-project.org

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> @ns6.gandi.net r-project.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 52927
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;r-project.org.   IN A

;; Query time: 347 msec
;; SERVER: 217.70.177.40#53(217.70.177.40)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 27 14:24:08 AEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42


$ dig @ns1.wu-wien.ac.at r-project.org

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> @ns1.wu-wien.ac.at r-project.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you can reach the Cran org site.  It appears to have been down a lot of the day.  I just got:
"cran.r-project.org’s server IP address could not be found."

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using R version 3.6 I would recommend downgrading to version 3.5.3 from 
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/

I've also had some issues with other functions when using v3.6. Let me know if this helps.

Best, 
Mostafa Lotfi

Answer (score 0):

If this is a work-related computer, I would check with your systems types.  There may be something in your setup that prevents you from installing R on your own without their blessings.