# Cannot install rstanarm (R crashes)

Tags: r, linux, package, rstudio, rstanarm

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780320/rstudio-crashing-when-installing-package-with-install-packages/59493513#59493513), but I tried the code Tiago Lubiana posts there, to no avail.

I haven't been able to install `rstanarm` after several attempts. R keeps crashing during the installation.

I did install rstan by running

```
install.packages("rstan", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE)
```

When I want to install `rstanarm`, nothing seems to work, though. I've tried the following:

1) `install.packages("rstanarm")`: R crashes and installs a folder called `00LOCK-rstanarm`, plus the corresponding `rstanarm` folder. When I open R, `rstanarm` is there, but after running `library(rstanarm)`, I get

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstanarm’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
>   shared object ‘rstanarm.so’ not found

By running `install.packages("rstanarm")` **again**, I get:

> ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/nalerive/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’ for modifying
>       Try removing ‘/home/nalerive/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/00LOCK-rstanarm’
>       Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘rstanarm’ had non-zero exit status

Deleting that folder has not solved the problem (but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a similar error with another package).

2) From [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm#development-version), running

```
if (!require(devtools)) { install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools) } 
install_github("stan-dev/rstanarm", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

leads to R crashing again, and the same folders as in 1) are installed. I also get the same error by running `library("rstanarm")`, namely:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstanarm’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
>   shared object ‘rstanarm.so’ not found

3) Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780320/rstudio-crashing-when-installing-package-with-install-packages?noredirect=1) I tried

```
install.packages("rstanarm", dependencies = TRUE, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

and R keeps crashing.

I've tried more things, like removing the `00LOCK-rstanarm` folder by means of `unlink("/home/nalerive/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/00LOCK-rstanarm/", recursive = TRUE)`; restarting R when indicated; checking my C++ toolchain (as suggested [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started)), etc... but nothing has worked. I really feel hopeless at this point.

I have R version 3.5.2, `rstan` version 2.19.2, and Linux 4.15.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.15.4-1~mx17+1 (2018-02-23)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess would be that your machine is running out of RAM. If so, you might try just using one or two cores by doing `export MAKEFLAGS=-j1` before starting R from a shell.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't work, unfortunately.