# How can I change the default browser used for package installation?

Tags: r, package

I am learning R recently and confused about the package installation, because I have found that the default browser for downloading the packages is Internet Explorer even if I have already changed it to Chrome on my computer, the Internet Explorer on my computer can not work. I have tried to reconfigure the global options list in R, but still get stuck.

Comment: What function are you using to download your packages ? The standard way to download a CRAN package is to use `install.packages()` which uses `download.files()` which is using one of your OS network library (one of "wininet", "libcurl", "wget", "curl", "lynx"). No browser are involved in the process. You can check your function internals using package:::function, `utils:::install.packages` for example.

Comment: @Wawv I use $install.packages()$ for downloading , but it always fails and shows that ‘unable to access index for repository …’ , if I copy the website shown and paste it in Chrome, I can get to the downloading page successfully.

Comment: I've found someone who had the same problem you do, you can check the answers :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599943/unable-to-install-packages-in-latest-version-of-rstudio-and-r-version-3-1-1